# php artisan route::list gives me an error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

When I type

```
php artisan route:list
```

I get

```
 Trying to get property of non-object
```

When I type

```
php artisan route:list -v
```

I get

```
Exception trace:
 () at /home/vagrant/Code/app/CategorySettings.php:31
 Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError() at /home/vagrant/Code/app/CategorySettings.php:31
 App\CategorySettings->getDefaultSettings() at /home/vagrant/Code/app/Http/Controllers/CategoryController.php:27
 App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController->__construct() at n/a:n/a
 ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:776
 Illuminate\Container\Container->build() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:627
 Illuminate\Container\Container->make() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:674
 Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:170
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getControllerMiddleware() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:151
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getMiddleware() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:119
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getRouteInformation() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:89
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getRoutes() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:76
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->fire() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:503
 Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:150
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:256
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:136
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:838
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:189
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:120
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:107
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at /home/vagrant/Code/artisan:35
```

Here is the related code

```
public function getDefaultSettings()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $categorySetting = $user->settings;   // <- line 31
...
}
```

Error message seems to tell me something wrong about $user
Thing is when I dd $categorySetting or $user, it gives me the correct objects...

```
    User {#418 ▼
  #table: "users"
  #fillable: array:16 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:20 [▶]
  #original: array:20 [▶]
  #relations: array:1 [▶]
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

Any idea what's wrong???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auth::user() only returns the User model when there's an user logged in, so when you dd on the browser, your user is returned.

However, when you call route:list from the cli, $user is null, hence 'Trying to get property of non-object'.

What you need to figure out is why route:list calls getDefaultSettings(). My guess would be that you're doing something on your routes.php file that calls that function.

One quick way to solve the problem is to check whether there's an user logged in before doing anything else with the user model by using the check method:

```
public function getDefaultSettings()
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $categorySetting = $user->settings;
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: nice catch! I will try it, and will probably work! Tx

Comment: Done, tx for your help!

Comment: but I was not doing anything.... I just call it in constructor of a controller :(

Comment: Glad it helped! Looking at your stack trace and Laravel's source code, it seems that route:list calls the controller's constructor to determine what middlewares it uses. That would explain your problem.